# Цвет текста в зависимости от фона

Tags: jquery, сss3

Есть ли возможность сделать цвет текста в зависимости от фона ?

На примере вот это вёрстки :

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000 0%, #000 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 100%);
}

p {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam quasi pariatur, natus iste, vitae illo recusandae tenetur maxime exercitationem reiciendis magni. Voluptatem odit ea voluptas a harum nisi voluptate hic veritatis, dolor quidem commodi enim
  beatae blanditiis ipsum expedita quis autem? Corporis ipsam, id perspiciatis eaque nobis laborum molestiae, dolor quam omnis aliquam reiciendis nisi cumque earum laudantium, quaerat maxime quis amet nulla voluptatem corrupti exercitationem odit dicta
  impedit dolorum. Laborum, perferendis! Vitae earum officiis, doloremque dicta, error similique corrupti minima deleniti rerum quas perferendis voluptates aspernatur ad iste saepe reiciendis minus deserunt quam ea cupiditate? Rem veniam facere deleniti.</p>
```

Как мы видим на фоне градиент двухцветный и шрифт (для удобства крупный).
 Фон разделён пополам.

**Как сделать чтобы, те буквы, что на чёрном стали белыми, а те,

что на белом чёрными ?**

Возможно ли это сделать средствами `css3` кроссбраузерно ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте что-то такое, не уверен насчёт надобности всех параметров для `p`, но работает.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000 0%, #000 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 100%);
}

p {
  height: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam quasi pariatur, natus iste, vitae illo recusandae tenetur maxime exercitationem reiciendis magni. Voluptatem odit ea voluptas a harum nisi voluptate hic veritatis, dolor quidem commodi enim
  beatae blanditiis ipsum expedita quis autem? Corporis ipsam, id perspiciatis eaque nobis laborum molestiae, dolor quam omnis aliquam reiciendis nisi cumque earum laudantium, quaerat maxime quis amet nulla voluptatem corrupti exercitationem odit dicta
  impedit dolorum. Laborum, perferendis! Vitae earum officiis, doloremque dicta, error similique corrupti minima deleniti rerum quas perferendis voluptates aspernatur ad iste saepe reiciendis minus deserunt quam ea cupiditate? Rem veniam facere deleniti.</p>
```

Comment: @МаксимЛенский нашёл только такой способ. Требований к конкретной реализации в вопросе не было :)

Comment: @МаксимЛенский а чем смущает, если не секрет? Сам я не имею глубоких познаний в этом, специализация немного другая, — но тоже было бы интересно)

Comment: прошу прощения, оказывается поддерживается везде : https://caniuse.com/#search=background-clip

Answer (score 5):

Не поддерживается в `ie` и `edge`

```css
div{
  background:linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%);
  padding:20px;
}
span{
  mix-blend-mode:difference;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span>asd asdas dasd aas dasfd ad as asda dasd as ad asd asd asdas dasd aas dasfd ad as asda dasd as ad asd asd asdas dasd aas dasfd ad as asda dasd as ad asd asd asdas dasd aas dasfd ad as asda dasd as ad asd asd asdas dasd aas dasfd ad as asda dasd as ad asd asd asdas dasd aas dasfd ad as asda dasd as ad asd asd asdas dasd aas dasfd ad as asda dasd as ad asd asd asdas dasd aas dasfd ad as asda dasd as ad asd</span></div>
```

Comment: а мозилке  поддерживается ?

Comment: да, поддерживается

Comment: @МаксимЛенский , c `body` не работает, почему - не знаю.

Comment: да я увидел уже... прикрутил html,body это особенность Opera

Comment: выбрал другой ответ так как он кроссбраузерный ...спс за помощь