# Текст черного цвета, часть которого находится на изображении, должен становится белым

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно чтобы часть черного текста, которая заходит на изображение, становилась белым цветом. Перепробовал все методы, но так и не пришел у нужному результату.

[image: Пример который должен получится]

Я попробовал сделать так:

```
.menu__title {
    font-size: 25vw;
    filter: invert(1) grayscale(1) contrast(1);
    color: #000;
}
```

Но получил это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (кнопка [edit])

Comment: Пробуй использовать свойство `css` `mix-blend-mode` https://hcdev.ru/css/mix-blend-mode/

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821444/%D0%A6%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqALYQkQCuDoHq01hS1OUIN7HX_j_4DqJYgO6c6Yj00Q&s) left/50% 100% no-repeat, url(https://www.olimptk.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/rastitelnyj-grunt.jpg) right/100% 100% no-repeat;
}

.container h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 70px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: black;
  filter: invert(90%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>lorem</h2>
</div>
```

Вот так это можно реализовать. Может не точь в точь, как Вы хотели, но мы видим, что это работает.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, beige 50%, black 50%);
}

.container h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: black;
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>lorem</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Для того чтобы изменить цвет части текста на изображении, вы можете использовать CSS и смешивание цветов с помощью background-clip. Вот пример того, как это можно сделать:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="your-image.jpg" alt="Your Image">
  <div class="text-overlay">
    <p class="black-text">Часть черного текста</p>
    <p class="white-text">Часть белого текста</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image-container img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.text-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.black-text {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.white-text {
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

В этом примере background-clip: text; и -webkit-background-clip: text; используются для смешивания цветов текста с фоном. Текст с классом black-text будет черным и проникает через белый фон, а текст с классом white-text будет белым на черном фоне.

Вы можете настроить размер шрифта, цвета и отступы под свои нужды.

Comment: Минус за ChatGPT.

Comment: Никто не заметил, что тут нет изменения цвета от фона, а просто слово разбито на 2 части и покрашено в разные цвета? В ответе выше так и показано...