# Необходимо сохранить фотографию (img) канваса wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Ellipse
                 Width="30"
                 Height="30"
                 Fill="{Binding Fill}" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <Canvas />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
             <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
             <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
         </Style>
     </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
 </ItemsControl>
```

Есть список фигур, которые расположены на canvas. Хочу добавить внешнюю кнопку при нажатии на которую сохраняется фотография canvas

Answer (score 0):

Создай обработчик события для кнопки, который будет выполнять логику сохранения. Используй класс RenderTargetBitmap для создания снимка Canvas.Сохрани снимок в файл с помощью BitmapEncoder, если надо могу скинуть пример кода полностью расписаным коментариями, что есть что

Comment: Очень прям хотелось-бы взглянуть на то, как вы это сделаете **соблюдая MVVM** (о котором гласит метка). Пока ваш ответ похож на комментарий.

Comment: Тут бы сначала до canvas достучаться. Снаружи ItemsPanelTemplate.

Answer (score -1):

Я не самый прошареный в програмировании, но стараюсь помочь своими и не только знаниями
private Canvas canvas;

```
public ICommand SaveCanvasCommand { get; }

public CanvasViewModel(Canvas canvas)
{
    this.canvas = canvas;
    SaveCanvasCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveCanvasImage);
}

private void SaveCanvasImage(object parameter)
{
    // Создайте RenderTargetBitmap для снимка Canvas
    RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)canvas.ActualWidth, (int)canvas.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

    // Вызовите Render метод, чтобы создать снимок Canvas
    renderBitmap.Render(canvas);

    // Создайте BitmapEncoder (например, PNGEncoder) для сохранения изображения
    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));

    // Выберите путь и имя файла 
    string filePath = "canvas_snapshot.png"; // ваш путь и имя файла

    // Создайте файл и сохраните в нем изображение
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        encoder.Save(fs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я надеюсь это не ChatGPT? Ибо если да, то знайте, он запрещен на этом ресурсе, и его использование карается баном. И да, тут нет MVVM.

Comment: Ну тогда увы, я без силен тут

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если быть точнее, то категорического запрета использование GPT при составлении ответов нет. GPT это как поисковая система, участники же не копипастят выдачу гугла в свои ответы, верно? А если бы копипастили бездумно, то что бы из этого вышло? Ничего хорошего. Так вот, у некоторых участников складывается впечатление, что GPT создаёт что-то уникальное и это можно не считать выдачей. К сожалению, это не так. Относиться к бездумной копипасте из GPT следует как к со страниц выдачи любого другого поисковика. Особо непонимающих рецидивистов конечно будем ограничивать. Голосуйте за контент.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ система сайта тех, кто имеет явно отрицательный рейтинг по ответам, заблокирует возможность их оставлять в принципе, [автоматически](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans). Голоса в данном конкретном случае решают больше, чем модераторы или кто-либо ещё.

Comment: @aepot Что-то тут не так. Поясню... 1. Вы модератор, который уже в который раз видит нарушение, и не пресекает его, вот тут GPT, у нас есть четкий пост на мете, где сказано "GPT запрещен и карается баном", если это не так, то напишите там ответ с текущими правками, да и на сколько я знаю, на "большом" сайте, после забастовки, администрация разрешила удалять явный GPT, тут явный GPT? Да. Ну так, где действия? 2. У этого вопроса есть и еще один ответ, который ответом не является, а является комментарием, так? Да. Ок, где действия? Извините, но со стороны выглядит весьма странно это все....

Comment: @aepot 3. Минусы, ок.. [поставил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1541413/220553), репорт не кидал, человеку от этого горячо или нет? Я думаю, нет, ибо последующие GPT (а я уверен в этом) ответы, набрали лайки, что ему сделает парочка минусов под одним, ну максимум двумя ответами? А ничего. Но это ведь GPT, явный и не скрывающийся GPT, тупо копипаст от бота, который, как я понял, еще и не про то (судя по комментарию, не спец в CSS). Будь там тревога, ответ скорей всего удалили бы, пользы было больше, а вместе с минусами, еще и бан получит. Вроде и чисто, и с баном, везде плюсы.

Comment: @aepot Если вы скажете "ну так, раз лайкают, то значит сообществу нравится ответ" - и тут я не согласен, ибо мы с вами прекрасно знаем как ставятся зачастую лайки, видят красивую обертку, простыню текста, вроде грамотно все и профессионально написано, человек ведь постарался, написал, а значит заслуживает автоматом лайк. Только единицы вчитываются в суть, и находят там явные проблемы (например тут, зачем в VM через конструктор внедряют Canvas?), комментируют это, критикуют, минусуют. Увы и ах, таковы реалии. Как прочитаете все, подотрите комменты тут.